# "Next Badge" already reached

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

In my profile I can see the following information about a badge:

[image]

As per my understanding the condition for the badge is already reached. Why have I not earned it yet?

Is it a bug?

Comment: The question record should be shown here. so it will be more clearer.

Comment: But i think i have a positive question record. can anyone explain i do not understand teh formual exactly